# Custom Data Binding path in Spring

Tags: java, spring, data-binding

While using `@ModelAttribute` in spring, the field name is the default path. We set values in JSP using `path="field_name"`. Is there a way I can define custom path for a field? E.g:
I would have a class `Guy`:

```
public class Guy {
    private String fullName;
    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

But I would have these input fields in the (say) sign up JSP:

```
<form:input path="name"/>
<form:input path="phone"/>
```

Comment: Nothing simple with just config.  Is it that big a problem to make your names match? :)

Comment: it's not about matching. I have pretty lengthy paths, some going down to 4th and 5th levels of nesting